# How can I add multiple objects in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

In the AR example project of apple there is an option for placing a chair in the room. What do I need to do to place multiple chairs in the code?
Would a simple append function do the trick?

When I tap on the chair option I need the first chair to be placed in the plane. If I tap again the option the chair should be placed once again. And I know I will need a delete function for this too. So how can I detect a long tap by the user?

Comment: If you have a `ARSCNView` you can add multiple objects to the scene through the `addChildNode()` method. You can remove an object from the scene through calling `removeFromParentNode()` on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic tap function to add a ball each time you tap the display.

```
 @objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

 let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint)
guard let result: ARHitTestResult = results.first else {
    return
}

// create a simple ball
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)

// create position of ball based on tap result
let position = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

// set position of ball before adding to scene
sphereNode?.position = position

 // each tap adds a new instance of the ball.
   self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode!)

  }
```

If you need the full swift code to get started...take a look at this earlier post [adds a cube.scn from a remote url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035962/can-i-get-3d-models-from-web-servers-on-swift/48046774#48046774)

You can do long press with

```
@objc func longPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


}
```

But its better to just detect you've tapped on an existing sphereNode you want to remove. You could add something like this to the above function.

```
let tappedNode = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), options: [:])

if !tappedNode.isEmpty {
  let node = tappedNode[0].node 
  node.removeFromParent()
  } else { 
 // add my new node
}
```

Comment: Thank You for that.

Comment: No worries. You will need to put.  self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))) In the viewDidLoad or  when the view loads... to call the handleTap function.